# Display html element from JSON object on ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been trying to embed html element from JSON object, and It is currently displaying the html as raw code instead.

Can someone please help me ?

detail.ts

```
 this.questionsData[i].question_type.title = "<ion-input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Short answer\"></ion-input>";
```

detail.html

```
<ion-item  *ngFor="let question of questionsData">
      {{question.title}}
      <br>
      Text : {{question.question_type.title}}
      <br>
     <div   [innerHTML]="question.question_type.title">
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

[image: example]

Isn't it should be input box under the text : , anyone know why it's not rendered ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach needs to change, do not include html tags in component block, instead add parameters as json data and set it at component. Then you can interpolate the tags in the template view.
Ex:

at the component:

```
this.inputDataArray = [{"title":"What cartoon do you like to watch?", "name":"inp1","placeholder":"short answer"},{"title":"What movie do you like to watch?", "name":"inp2","placeholder":"short answer"}];
```

at the view:

```
       <ion-item  *ngFor="let question of inputDataArray">
          {{question.title}}
          <br>
          Text : <input name={{question.name}} placeholder={{question.placeholder}} />
          <br>

    </ion-item>
```

Its just a reference, Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much, this approach much cleaner for me, I also use *ngIf now, so the templating is done on html file, not on ts file

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

InnerHtml will only help to render pure html code on run time, you can't use ionic components to render dynamically using innerhtml. I think you need to use dynamic component loader feature in angular here. You can refer this link on use cases of this feature https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<div [innerHTML]="data.text"></div>
```